# Difference in serverless.zip file sizes - what could be causing it

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

A colleague and I are both working with serverless, both on windows 10, with the latest serverless version of 1.37.0 with the same npm version of 6.70.

Yet running the serverless command,  his computer bundles up the node modules folder to upload a package of on average 8-9 MB.. yet mine bundles to 20Mb.. i cannot figure out what could be causing this. 
Dev dependencies are being excluded so not sure why my laptop is packaging it up so inefficiently compared to his.

Does any one know of any reasons as to why this could be? or any other recommendations?